# Django 1.3 specify the template to use in argument with inclusion_tag

Tags: django, templates, tags

I am currently having 2 templatetags for nearly the same thing:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('content.html')
def content(key, lazy=False, params=''):
    return {'key': key, 'lazy': js_bool(lazy), 'params': params}

@register.inclusion_tag('spec.html')
def spec(key, lazy=False, params=''):
    return {'key': key, 'lazy': js_bool(lazy), 'params': params}
```

I'd like to merge them as only the template to use change, how could I do that ?

Comment: As an aside you really shouldn't be using Django 1.3 any more. It hasn't had security fixes applied to it for ages and will probably open your website up to hacks. Best bet would be to upgrade to Django 1.8 as soon as possible since that is the newest long term support of Django and will be supported for at least 2 years.

Comment: At least 3 years even ;)

Comment: Yeah sure guys as if I had the choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
def tag(key, lazy=False, params=''):
    return {'key': key, 'lazy': js_bool(lazy), 'params': params}

register.inclusion_tag('content.html', name='content')(tag)
register.inclusion_tag('spec.html', name='spec')(tag)
```

Python decorators are nothing more than syntactic helpers, you can replace

```
@decorator
def function():
    pass
```

by

```
def function():
    pass
function = decorator(function)
```